# Hitting AWS Lambda Memory limit in Python

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am looking for some advice on this project.  My thought was to use Python and a Lambda to aggregate the data and respond to the website.  The main parameters are date ranges and can be dynamic.

**Project Requirements:**

- Read data from monthly return files stored in JSON (each file contains roughly 3000 securities and is 1.6 MB in size)
- Aggregate the data into various buckets displaying counts and returns for each bucket (for our purposes here lets say the buckets are Sectors and Market Cap ranges which can vary)
- Display aggregated data on a website

**Issue I face**
I have successfully implemted this in an AWS Lambda, however in testing requests that are 20 years of data (and yes I get them), I begin to hit the memory limits in AWS Lambda.

**Process I used:**
All files are stored in S3, so I use the boto3 library to obtain the files, reading them into memory.  This is still small and not of any real significance.

I use `json.loads` to convert the files into a pandas dataframe.  I was loading all of the files into one large dataframe. - This is where the it runs out of memory.

I then pass the dataframe to custom aggregations using `groupby` to get my results.  This part is not as fast as I would like but does the job of getting what I need.

The end result dataframe that is then converted back into JSON and is less than 500 MB.

This entire process when it works locally outside the lambda is about 40 seconds.
I have tried running this with threads and processing single frames at once but the performance degrades to about 1 min 30 seconds.

While I would rather not scrap everything and start over, I am willing to do so if there is a more efficient way to handle this.  The old process did everything inside of node.js without the use of a lambda and took almost 3 minutes to generate.

**Code currently used**
I had to clean this a little to pull out some items but here is the code used.
Read data from S3 into JSON this will result in a list of string data.

```
 while not q.empty():
            fkey = q.get()


            try:
                obj = self.s3.Object(bucket_name=bucket,key=fkey[1])
                json_data = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

                results[fkey[1]] = json_data
            except Exception as e:
                results[fkey[1]] = str(e)
            q.task_done()
```

Loop through the JSON files to build a dataframe for working

```
for k,v in s3Data.items():        
        lstdf.append(buildDataframefromJson(k,v))

def buildDataframefromJson(key, json_data):

    tmpdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ticker','totalReturn','isExcluded','marketCapStartUsd',
                                  'category','marketCapBand','peGreaterThanMarket', 'Month','epsUsd']
                         )
     #Read the json into a dataframe
    tmpdf = pd.read_json(json_data,
                         dtype={
                            'ticker':str,
                            'totalReturn':np.float32,
                            'isExcluded':np.bool,
                            'marketCapStartUsd':np.float32,
                            'category':str,
                            'marketCapBand':str,
                            'peGreaterThanMarket':np.bool,
                            'epsUsd':np.float32
                            })[['ticker','totalReturn','isExcluded','marketCapStartUsd','category',
                        'marketCapBand','peGreaterThanMarket','epsUsd']]
    dtTmp = datetime.strptime(key.split('/')[3], "%m-%Y")
    dtTmp = datetime.strptime(str(dtTmp.year) + '-'+ str(dtTmp.month),'%Y-%m')
    tmpdf.insert(0,'Month',dtTmp, allow_duplicates=True)

    return tmpdf
```

Comment: theres no way to get around the 3GB Lambda memory limit unfortunately especially if you're using `pandas` which is a memory goliath. one work around is you have an EC2 instance somewhere and you can have the Lambda trigger code on the EC2 instance using `ssm`

Comment: We really can't optimise your code based on a general description.

Comment: Well, first I think we need your prerequisites. Can you check how much memory your application requires? depending on that you should be able to either increase the memory required by lambda or just deploy the code on an appropriate instance and run it with a lambda call using a VPC endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the thought about an EC2, I might be able to make that work, not sure what my company restrictions are around usage there.   @Alex, this was a theoretical question not a code optimization one.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: What I mean is that maybe your calculations can be done without holding all the data in memory at once. Could you perhaps use a database to do the aggregations?

Comment: Alex thanks for the clarification.  Unfortunately I am limited by the way the system was designed initially.  The files are all located in an S3 environment and stored as JSON.  I wish they were were stored in our database as it would make life easier however I was told that is not an option for this project.  I have to work with the JSON files that were stored.  We tried doing some pre-aggregation on the files in pieces but as the requirements changed this was no longer possible and we had to build on the fly.  Thoughts on doing this all as arrays?  I know the code will be ugly but faster?